# Fastest way to import large data to ERPNext

Tags: database, erp, erpnext, frappe

Hello Beautiful People,

We have planned to migrate our existing system to ERPNext. But we've noticed that importing large amount of data takes a long time, importing and submitting 80,000 Delivery notes took 3 days (Linked with Sales Order and Sales Invoice).

I am wondering if there is a better way to import large data. We are using AWS EC2 (c5n.xlarge vCPU 4, RAM 10.5 GiB), suggestions for increasing server capacity and configurations also encouraged.

Can we use ERPNext Data Migration Tool? I have tried to connect with another MariaDB Server, no luck. I don't know how it works.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you try ```bench import-csv ~/delivery_notes.csv```  ? https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en/guides/data/import-large-csv-file

Comment: Yes, that's how I am importing large data.

Comment: Migrating such data is really hard but somehow you manage it. I would add more cpu for a limited time. Or I would use some spare computers for that job. After that you can backup and restore data to target server.